# How to distinguish between two httpget parameters that accept same input argument?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<SupplierInfo>>> GetItemsByRequestID(int RequestID)
        {
            var item = await this.supplierInfoRepository.GetItemByRequestID(RequestID);
            return Ok(item);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<SupplierInfo>>> GetItems(int id)
        {
            var item = await this.supplierInfoRepository.GetItem(id);
            return Ok(item);
        }
```

I have two Httpget requests, How should I distinguish them because both are accepting an integer.
One is GetItemByRequestID and other one is GetItems.

Should I change one to controller/requestid/id and the other one to
controller/id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Items controller then getting item by id might look like this

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
```

and getting by specific request id

```
[HttpGet("GetItemsByRequestID/{RequestID}")]
```